# How to grep for cases where a pattern doesn't exist without perl-like lookahead?

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a regular expression for when a pattern doesn't happen (specifically, I want to pull a list of folders and sub-folders from a drive, so I'm looking for anything that doesn't end in `\\.[[:alnum:]]{1,4}$`). Because this pattern goes into `list.files`, I can't use PERL-like lookahead (right?). Is there a way for me to achieve it other than first putting everything into a vector and then running a grep on it with lookahead?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: Like I said - I tried lookahead, but that didn't work. I'm at a loss as to what else I could try...

Comment: Sorry, `list.files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was stupid. The answer was staring me in the face the whole time - `list.dirs` lists only directories, while `list.files` lists all files. I'm not sure why trying the former at first didn't seem to give me the result I was looking for...

Comment: I tried again - for some reason list.dirs is significantly slower than list.files -- so slow in fact that I thought my R session froze the first couple of times I tried it. That's why I ended up trying list.files instead...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with `R`'s regex, but this seems to work for me:

```
'.*[^[:alnum:]].{0,3}$'
```

What it means is that you want at least one of the 3 last character to not be an alpha-num

```
files <- c("my_file", "script.php", "foo!faa", "test123.321tset", "colors.red")

files[grep(".*[^[:alnum:]].{0,3}$", files)]
# => "script.php" "foo!faa"    "colors.red"
```

Comment: the problem is that R's list.dirs output doesn't have a period at the end of folder names, so this won't work.

Comment: The period in my regex matches any characters. I'm not sure what you're trying to do..

Comment: I know what the period means. I'm not sure how your solution helps find the cases where there IS no extension (e.g., a folder named "foobar"). For example, from your set, the only case I would like to be able to identify is "my_file" which is what a folder generally looks like (no extension). Moreover, some files have a 4 digit extenstion (jpeg) and those will also be missed by your solution.